# Conditional joinLeft on magento collection

Tags: mysql, magento, left-join

My SQL query statement is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * from `customer_address_entity_varchar` 
WHERE attribute_id=31) AS `ce3` 
ON main_table.customer_id=ce3.entity_id
```

and I need it to be translated into Magento style.
I have tried

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection'); 
$tel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('2', 'telephone');

$collection->getSelect()  
    ->joinLeft(array('ce3' => 'customer_address_entity_varchar'), 'main_table.customer_id=ce3.entity_id', array('telephone' => 'value'))
    ->where('ce3.attribute_id='.$tel->getAttributeId())
```

But this didn't work because the where statement is applied after the  join causing the total number of queries to be less than sales_flat_order_grid.

Comment: you can use direct sql query in magento http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/

Answer (score 6):

I believe that this solves your problem:

```
 $collection -> getSelect() -> joinLeft(array("oauth"=>'customer_entity_varchar'), 
'main_table.customer_id=oauth.entity_id and oauth.attribute_id = 156',
 array('OauthProvider' => "value"));
```